# Warning: require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0

Tags: php, include

I am trying to include a php file in a page via

```
  require_once(http://localhost/web/a.php)
```

I am getting an error

```
 Warning: require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by   allow_url_include=0
```

I changed `allow_url_include=1` in the php.ini and that worked but I don't think that everybody will let me change their php.ini file.

So, is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The warning is generated because you are using a full URL for the file that you are including. This is NOT the right way because this way you are going to get some HTML from the webserver. Use:

```
require_once('../web/a.php');
```

so that webserver could EXECUTE the script and deliver its output, instead of just serving up the source code (your current case which leads to the warning).

Answer (score 26):

I had this same error while trying to include a PHP file in my Wordpress theme. I was able to get around it by referencing the file name using `dirname(__FILE__)`. I couldn't use relative paths since my file was going to be included in different places throughout the theme, so something like `require_once '../path-to/my-file'` wouldn't work.

Replacing `require_once get_template_directory_uri() . '/path-to/my-file'` with `require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/path-to/my-file'` did the trick.

Comment: This may work in cases where the require_once can be evaluated later, as it seems to do so not in the pre-compile phase, but later in the function evaluation phase. In cases where you need to require the file prior to another file being required with out the use of the dirname() call (in a parent theme for example), it prevents any opportunity for your file to be evaluated first...  At least this appears to be the case for WordPress servers.

Comment: If You are using WordPress, just use get_template_directory() instead of get_template_directory_uri() it`s working

Answer (score 20):

try to use

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/web/a.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Great solution, avoids some annoying Wordpress errors that the above can't seem to circumvent

Answer (score 7):

You have to put the path to the file. For example:

```
require_once('../web/a.php');
```

You cannot get the file to require it from internet (with http protocol) it's restricted. The files must be on the same server. With Possibility to see each others (rights)

```
Dir-1 -
         > Folder-1 -> a.php
Dir-2 -
         > Folder-2 -> b.php

To include a.php inside b.php => require_once('../../Dir-1/Folder-1/a.php');
To include b.php inside a.php => require_once('../../Dir-2/Folder-2/b.php');
```

Comment: i know that.. but what if i want to include same file in two directories.. like file `a.php` is placed in DIR 1 and now i want to include it in DIR 3 file.. and one file having `a.php` from dir 3 is included in one of dir 1 files... so it gives errors `a.php` does not exist

Comment: Please show me the directory structure. Without it it is hard for me to help.

Comment: it is Directory 1 --> Folder 1 --> a.php and Directory 2 --> Folder 2 --> b.php [it has require_once('../../a.php')] .. now when i include b.php in one of the files in Directory 1 then it throws me an error that a.php does not exist which is true as per directory structure

Comment: I have edit my previous answer, because here there is no post structure for a better "view".

Answer (score 5):

**WORDPRESS is having this error mostly:** 
**SOLUTION:** 
Locate your PHP installed directory on Remote live hosting SERVER or "Local Server" 
In case of Windows os 
for example if you using xampp or wamp webserver. it will be in xammp directory
'c:\xammp\php' 
**Note:** *For Unix/Linux OS, locate your PHP directory in Webserver*

Find & Edit **PHP.INI** file 
Find *'allow_url_include'* 
replace it with value 'on' 
***allow_url_include=On*** 
Save you **php.ini** & **RESTART** you web-server.

Answer (score 4):

```
require_once('../web/a.php');
```

If this is not working for anyone, following is the good Idea to include file anywhere in the project.

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__)."/../../includes/enter.php";
```

This code will get the file from 2 directory outside of the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

include and require functions require **file path**, but you are giving **file URI** instead. The parameter should not be the one that includes http/https.

Your code should be something like:

```
include ("folder/file.php");
```

Answer (score 2):

**For me the resolution with sending data on a PHP request:**

```
$ch = curl_init('https://localhost/request.php');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_REQUEST));

echo curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WordPress and have trouble with this error on *require* or *include*, use
`get_template_directory()` instead of `get_theme_file_uri()`. The included HTTP protocol is the problem in this case.

Example:

```
require_once( get_template_directory() . '\inc\file.php');
```

Results in (on localhost):

```
C:\XAMPP\htdocs\your-db\wp-content\themes\your-theme\inc\file.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once(APPPATH.'web/a.php');
```

worked for me in codeigniter

check [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235821/how-to-handle-a-codeigniter-pdf-generator)

Answer (score 0):

echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/web/a.php'); //Best Example